# Array of pointer to arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

In C++ is possible to create a pointer to a 2-D array of certain dimensions like this:

```
int(*ptr)[n] = A
```

where "ptr" is the pointer to create and A is the pointer to the first row in the array (and n in the number of columns). Thus, this code will work:

```
int Arr[3][3]
int (*ptr)[3] = Arr;
```

Now, my question is "How I create an array of pointers like ptr?"

Comment: I suspect we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please take one step back and focus on what you want to achieve with this. I think you can get help with that, but not with what you are asking here for.

Comment: Note that these are called "C-type arrays", and the general consensus is that you should rather use C++ containers (like `vector`) instead, unless you have a compelling *reason* to use a C construct.

Answer (score 3):

> How I create an array of pointers like ptr?

There are different ways of doing this as shown below:

##### Method 1

We can use `decltype` with modern C++:

```
int Arr[3][3]{};       //Arr is a 2d array of type int [3][3]
int (*ptr)[3] = Arr;  //ptr is a pointer to an array of size 3 with elements of type int 


//lets create an array of pointers like ptr 
decltype(ptr) f[10] ={ptr};    //f is an array of size 10 with elements of type int (*)[3]
```

---

##### Method 2

Here we use `typedef` or `using` for creating an alias for the type `int (*)[3]`

```
int Arr[3][3]{};       //Arr is a 2d array of type int [3][3]
int (*ptr)[3] = Arr;  //ptr is a pointer to an array of size 3 with elements of type int 

//create an alias for the type int (*)[3]
using arrPtr = int (*)[3];                  

//using arrPtr = decltype(ptr); //this also works 

//lets create an array of pointers like ptr 
arrPtr f[10] = {ptr};       //f is an array of size 10 with elements of type int (*)[3]
```

---

##### Method 3

Here we explicitly write the type of the array `f` without using `decltype`

```
int Arr[3][3]{};       //Arr is a 2d array of type int [3][3]
int (*ptr)[3] = Arr;  //ptr is a pointer to an array of size 3 with elements of type int 


//lets create an array of pointers like ptr 
int (*f[10])[3] = {ptr};       //f is an array of size 10 with elements of type int (*)[3]
```

Comment: Method 3: use a `typedef` or `using` alias, eg: `using arrptr = int (*)[3]; ... int Arr[3][3]{}; arrptr ptr = Arr; ... arrptr f[10] = {ptr};`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, it felt like i was missing some method. Thanks! I've added your suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, my question is "How I create an array of pointers like ptr?"

```
int (*x[10])[5];
```

`x` is an array of 10 pointers to array of 5 `int`

And the initialization example:

```
int a[3][4];
int b[5][4];
int c[7][4];

int (*ptr[3])[4] = {a,b,c};
```

Comment: I think OP wants the second shown code to be useable (though the rest of the question is unclear to me) and I do not see how your solution allows that.

Comment: @Yunnosch The question is quite clear for me.